# View PDF in Browser side by side view

Tags: html, pdf

In the application my team is building we have a bunch of pdf's embedded in the html for the user to view applicable information. My issue comes with one of those pdf's which I am being told must be displayed side by side, or in other words two pages next to each other.

Is there a way to do this across all browsers? I have been searching, but have had no luck so far and everything I have tried has failed.

my object tag looks like this

```
<object class="pdf" data="http://socialmenace.net/sample2.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500px">
  <h5>It seems like you cannot preview PDF's in your browser. In that case please use the download button below.</h5>
</object>
```

and here is a jsFiddle to play with. http://jsfiddle.net/uqE8k/4/

Comment: your fiddle only have a single page PDF?

Comment: Does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/uqE8k/3/ I just copied and pasted the object code so it's there twice and changed width to 50% for both

Comment: Sorry, just updated the fiddle...I just grabbed the closest pdf I had.

Comment: @AeroX, I wish it did...but this pdf can have up to ten thousand pages...so I don't really want to put the object tag that many times.

Comment: For clarity... Do you want to display two `.pdf` documents side-by-side or view one `.pdf` document in a book like mode (two page view)?

Comment: one pdf document in book mode I guess you could call it. I was having trouble finding the right name to call it :)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParams.pdf it's a `.pdf` from Adobe specifying parameters you can add on the end of the URL to configure parameters such as the view mode.

Comment: @AeroX I have read that document from top to bottom already, but I am not opening up the pdf in a new page... hence my issue... it has to be in the same view

Comment: http://blog.gilbertconsulting.com/2009/08/how-to-force-pdf-to-open-at-particular.html - this may be the problem and the solution - are you creating the PDF yourself?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I can't really rely on how the pdf is made...this is going to be used by many people uploading their own pdfs.

Comment: I tried the appending URL #zoom=200 etc. for you - one that does work is #page=2 - document starts at page 2 (you can do this in your fiddle) - only (super hacky) way  could see is to have 2 PDF readers side by side - one with page1 - one with page 2 - over-ride all page functions and create a custom button that when clicked changes the URL to #page=3 and #page=4 -> looking at what I have read I don't THINK it is possible but there are always smart people who prove me wrong when I say that (so fingers crossed for you!)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I cannot zoom in on the pdf's though. This is interior's of books, like actual books. It has to be presented in a certain way to the users and I really don't have that much lea way with scrolling and zoom. Unfortunately, I can't do the two pdf trick...these books are extremely heavy to load and it already take forever for one to load...when I did two of them it crashed the browser...